# Determine if it's end of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, crop

Is there a way to determine if it has reached the end of a string or not. 
Right now I'm using this PHP function

```
<?php echo substr('some text', 0, 7)?>
```

To limit the character number to be displayed. Now I would like to add "..." to the text but only if it's not the end of the string.

So when I have a text "Hello!" it would display the whole thing and if I have a text "Determine" it would not only display "Determi" but also adds this "..." like that "Determi...".

I've tried these ellipse and overflow ways but they didn't work for me.

Would something like this described above be possible?

Comment: Have you looked into [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)? You can use that to compare to the length you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with the built-in function [`mb_strimwidth`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php):

```
<?php
echo mb_strimwidth("some text", 0, 7, "...")
// output: "some te..."
?>
```

Comment: oh nice didn't know that one !

Comment: Nice indeed. Good to know there's a function that small and simple for that!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this :

```
<?php echo (strlen($text) > 7 ? (substr($text, 0, 7) . '...') : $text) ?>
```

If string has more than 7 characters, you echo only the first 7 ones and add ..., otherwise you just echo the text

Answer (score 0):

```
function trimStr($str, $len = 7) {
  return strlen($str) > $len ? substr($str, 0, $len) . '...' : $str;
}
```